# CodeChef Morning Commute wrong answer

Tags: java, algorithm

Here's the question: 
The Chef commutes to work every day using the city's underground metro. The schedule for the trains has recently been changed and he wants to know how long it will take to travel from the station nearest to his house and the station nearest to his restaurant.
The Chef doesn't want to change the route he took before, so he simply has to find out how long it will take to reach his restaurant along his usual route. This route is given by a sequence of stations s0, s1, ..., sn where s0 is the station where the Chef enters the metro and sn is the station where the Chef exits the metro.
Trains are scheduled to run between every two consecutive stations si-1 and si. Such a schedule is specified by three integers xi, li, and fi. This means that the first train on this line starts operating at time xi. The time it takes this train to travel from si-1 and si is exactly li units. Finally, a train departs from station si-1 every fi minutes following the previous train. That is, a train departs at time xi, xi+fi, xi+2fi, and so on.
The Chef is very experienced at navigating the metro so the time it takes him to transfer between trains at a given station is essentially zero. Thus, if the Chef arrives at a station, say si, the moment that the train from si to si+1 is scheduled to depart, he skillfully hops on this next train. However, if the Chef arrives when no train to si+1 is scheduled to depart, he must wait until the scheduled departure time.
Help the Chef figure out how long it will take him to travel from station s0 to station sn. You may assume that the Chef is already at station s0 at time 0.
Input

The first line consists of a single integer denoting the number of test cases (at most 50). Each test case begins with a line containing a single integer n between 1 and 1000 indicating the number of lines the Chef must traverse (so there are n+1 stations s0, s1, ..., sn). The next n lines describe the train schedules between stations, one per line. The i'th such line gives the values xi, li, and fi for the train that travels between stations si-1 and si.
The xi values will be between 0 and 1000 and the li and fi values will be between 1 and 1000.
Output

For each test case you are to output a single integer denoting the minimum time t for which the Chef can reach station sn using the given route. Remember, the Chef starts at s0 at time 0.
Example

Input:
3
2
0 4 7
0 6 5
2
0 1 2
6 2 10
2
1 2 3
0 2 3

Output:
11
8
5

Here's the link to the problem: http://www.codechef.com/problems/COMMUTE/

I've tried multiple solutions but couldn't figure out why Codechef is giving me "wrong answer" messages. Note that my program produced the same output as the example output in Codechef, and I even made up some of my own numbers and plug them in, and my program still gives the correct (I calculated them by myself) result.

My thought process is:

- ---- for starting time
- ____ for traveling time
- ++++ for waiting time

In this case, the time required for traveling from station1 to station2 is starting time+traveling time for station2:

```
------_____++++++
-----------------------____+++|+++|+++
```

In this case, the time required for traveling from station2 to station3 is starting time, treveling time and 2 waiting time of station3.

```
-----------------------____+++|+++|+++
-------______________++++|++++|++++|++++|
```

And the total time would be the same from station2 to station3. Because it's linear?

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int cases = in.nextInt();
    int n = 0;

    int [] t = new int [cases];
    for(int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
        int stations = in.nextInt();
        int [] start = new int [stations];
        int [] travel = new int [stations];
        int [] gap = new int [stations];

        for(int j = 0; j < stations; j++) {
            start[j] = in.nextInt();
            travel[j] = in.nextInt();
            gap[j] = in.nextInt();
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < (stations-1); j++) {
            n = 0;
            if(j==0) {
                if(start[j] + travel[j] > start[j+1]+(n*gap[j+1])) {
                    while(start[j] + travel[j] > start[j+1]+(n*gap[j+1])) {
                        n++;
                    }
                    t[i] = start[j+1] + (n*gap[j+1]) + travel[j+1];
                } else {
                    t[i] = start[j+1] + travel[j+1];
                }
            } else {
                if(t[i] > start[j+1]+(n*gap[j+1])) {
                    while(t[i] > start[j+1]+(n*gap[j+1])) {
                        n++;
                    }
                    t[i] = start[j+1] + (n*gap[j+1]) + travel[j+1];
                } else {
                    t[i] = start[j+1] + travel[j+1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
        System.out.println(t[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've remove unnecessary code, blank lines and comments. Also done some formatting...

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach You've left the first two lines of code outside the code block.

Comment: What are the numbers corresponding to your example?

Comment: Hi MarvinEmilBrach thanks for doing that. and @beaker the numbers are 3
2
0 4 7
0 6 5
2
0 1 2
6 2 10
2
1 2 3
0 2 3

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach. I also used some random examples I came up with. Which all worked as expected. I wonder if it is because either input formatting or if there is some other cases that I missed? Thanks you guys.

Comment: You should add the question itself in your question's body and don't rely on links (that tend to die)

Comment: In that case I don't understand your diagrams because to travel from station1 to station2 would be a start time of 0 and travel time of 4.

Comment: @beaker the diagrams I drew were just random examples to show my idea. They are not the actual examples. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I don't see any errors in your logic and it doesn't appear that you could be overflowing. Sorry, but I'm stumped.

Comment: Haha! lol. Thanks anyways. I sent it to my CS professor let's hope he has some stuff to show me :)